# Trailing slash Umbraco and HTTPs

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, umbraco

I have an Umbraco  site that sits behind a Netscaler.  All requests are translated from http to https (via Netscaler) and a trailing slash is appended using IIS rewrites.  The IIS re-write rule is causing a HTTPS request (without a trailing slash) to insert an additional request with a Status of 302. Essentially:

https://example.com/news (Status 301)

http://example.com/news/ (Status 302)

https://example.com/news/ (Status 200)

Ideally I would like one 301 Redirect and then a 200 - I need to remove the temporary redirect

The IIS rewrite rule to add trailing slashes:

```
<rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*[^/])$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="POST" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(asp|aspx|axd|asmx|css|htc|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|ico|pdf|txt|htm|html|php|xml)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/Base" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="cdv=1" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
    </rule>
```

I have already implemented in the umbracoSettings.config file

```
{addTrailingSlash}true{/addTrailingSlash}
```

I have also tried the rewrite rule

```
 <rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

But this causes an infinite loop of 301's and the page dies

Running out of idea's

Comment: No replies - someone must have had this issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it.

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
```

Is not enough even though the redirect is Permanent the protocol is standard port 80.  The action type need to updated to:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

You need to specify https complete with the host and the {R:1}/ in the url attribute